How to highlight buffer text as it is inserted in input()?
I wish that the string I am inserting when prompted after a input() function and before hitting Enter is highlighted in the current buffer and such a highlight is deleted once I press Enter.
My attempt is the following:
vim9script

var match_id = 0
augroup SEARCH_HI | autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineChanged @ if match_id > 0 | matchdelete(match_id) | endif | match_id = matchadd('IncSearch', getcmdline())
augroup END
var search = input("String to search: ")
if match_id > 0
  matchdelete(match_id)
endif
autocmd! SEARCH_HI
augroup! SEARCH_HI

but nothing seems to happen.

use an explicit redraw

redraw! after matchadd() did the job actually! Thanks!

@ChristianBrabandt or OP, please add an answer!

As suggested, the problem has been solved by adding a redraw! after the matchadd():
vim9script

var match_id = 0
augroup SEARCH_HI | autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineChanged @ if match_id > 0 | matchdelete(match_id) | endif | match_id = matchadd('IncSearch', getcmdline()) | redraw!
augroup END
var search = input("String to search: ")
if match_id > 0
  matchdelete(match_id)
endif
autocmd! SEARCH_HI
augroup! SEARCH_HI

